# Migrating to Mvc, possible new approach for handling css/image requests?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Our current asp.net web forms software maintains a handler that writes css and images to the context.

So you get a nice group of the resources as well as easy urls and more maintainability like so:

```
<link style="text/css" href="css.axd?prod=filename" />
<img src="img.axd?prod=filename" />
```

I'm curious if there are any approaches with Mvc that have more advantages using a controller ... can it even  be done?? Based on my cursory research and understanding of Mvc, it seems like this is doable.

Thanks

EDIT: The goal here is to create a similar mechanism (regardless of implementation) that makes our Views clean and more maintainable when requesting images and css.

The implementation needs to also take into account that themeing needs to be addressed on-demand as well (which is what our handler does as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actions can [FileContentResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filecontentresult.aspx) or so ([return File(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492897.aspx) overloads), so essentially yes - you can implement this behavior in controllers and actions.

But pay careful attention to performance. Every "regular" resource served by the server (CSS, JS etc.) is cached by default in several tiers, both at the server side and the client side. When applying these server-side call, you eliminate this nice default cache and you must apply it yourself in code or so.

Comment: Yes, the caching is also manually performed within our handler as well for this very reason. Appreciate the heads up nevertheless. Thank you for the direction. If this works, I'll give you the answer tick =P

Comment: Thank you for the reminder! Yes, it did. I actually chose to go with a `CotentResult`, it fit our needs just fine. Implementing the two layer cache was fun process lol but works like a charm. I couldn't produce any arguments as to why doing it this way would prove better than using handler approach as previously mentioned. Any thoughts on the issue?

Comment: It can still be a handler. I don't have an argue towards MVC action. Mainly a matter of personal preference / comfort.

Answer (score -1):

HTML helpers.

```
@Url.Content("~/images/image.png")
@Url.Content("~/styles/style.css")
```

or introduce new HTML helper

public static string Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string imglink) {}

and you can use it like this:

```
@Html.Image("logo.png")
```

**Though for styles and scripts I would recommend [Combres](http://combres.codeplex.com/)**